# HTMX: Why isn't the default target working?

Tags: htmx

According to the HTMX [documentation](https://htmx.org/docs/#targets), the default target for an Ajax response is the innerHTML of the element making the call. Yet in my sample code below, where the `span` makes a request to `/books/count`, the `hx-target` on the form is being used instead of the response being loaded into the empty `span`. Is this correct behavior?

Do you always have to do `hx-target=this` if there's another `hx-target` on any parent element? That seems to nullify the whole idea of a "default target."

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Book Recommendations</h1>
    <form hx-post="/book" hx-swap="beforeend" hx-target="#new-book" class="mb-3">
        <span hx-get="/books/count" hx-trigger="load"></span>
    </form>

    <div id="new-book">
        <p>a table goes here</p>
        <!-- response from /books/count is going here -->
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [inheritance](https://htmx.org/docs/#inheritance):

> Most attributes in htmx are inherited: they apply to the element they are on as well as any children elements. This allows you to “hoist” attributes up the DOM to avoid code duplication.

and

> Automatic inheritance can be disabled using the [hx-disinherit](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-disinherit/) attribute.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Now that you mention it, I do recall reading about hoisting in the HTMX e-book. So in that case I can either set `hx-disinherit="hx-get" (or ="*") on the parent form, or do `hx-target=this` on the span. Thanks!